# Как исключить теги из поиска?

Tags: php, sqlite

У меня в базе хранится html-код и мне нужно выполнить поиск по содержимому тегов, не затрагивая сами теги. Например, при поиске script не выводить записи, в которых содержится `<script>`, но выводить записи, в тексте тегов которых, есть слово script (`<p>script</p>`).

Comment: Хранить в базе отдельно версию текста с вычищенными тегами и искать по этой версии

Comment: Я думал так сделать, но у меня слишком большая база..

Comment: Если базу можно поместить на терабайтный диск, то это маленькая база

Comment: Возможно.. Но не для меня..

Comment: @СергейЛукин если sql поддерживает ретроспективную проверку, то можно например с помощью REGEXP: [`(?<!<)/?script`](https://regex101.com/r/dCxjNf/1)

Comment: Похоже, не поддерживает.. Это можно как нибудь исправить?

Comment: https://sitear.ru/material/php-parsing-html-simple-html-dom